# android button visibility not working

Tags: android, button

```
Button android:id="@+id/statistics_button" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      style="@style/ButtonText"
      android:layout_margin="1dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/statistics_button"
      android:paddingLeft="10px"
      android:paddingRight="10px"
      android:layout_marginRight="10px"
      android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

I have this button in one of my xml layout.but **android:visibility="invisible"** is not working.By "not working" i mean while displaying it is getting visible.

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Comment: Who gave "-1" please explain.

Comment: ur question is not clear.what do mean by visibility not working? Explain ur question briefly...

Comment: Any chances that you post the code that shows the view again? Have you checked that the condition isn't always true (otherwise it auto-negates the xml attribute here)?

Comment: @alextsc, I tested.even if the condition is false,it is getting visible. :(

Comment: Everything is working fine.I wrongly asked question.Sorry guys for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: Note that `gone` is not the same thing as `invisible`. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility). So not a fix, more of a workaround.

Comment: Why can't you use setVisibility(View.GONE) instead of setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)?

Comment: @harmjanr Thanks,Read my edited question please. View.GONE is different than View.INVISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

Use android:visibility="gone"..it will solve your problem..